# clicked listview to open detail view in android

Tags: javascript, android, xml

I have an XML file that consists of a title, a link to the image, and description.

exp.

```
<?xml ?>
<wrap>
 <content>
  <title>Title</title>
  <img>link of image</img>
  <desc>Descrioption</desc>
 </content>
 <content>
  <title>Title</title>
  <img>link of image</img>
  <desc>Descrioption</desc>
 </content>
 <content>
  <title>Title</title>
  <img>link of image</img>
  <desc>Description</desc>
 </content>
</wrap>
```

I want the title shown on Listview which when clicked will open a detail page complete with titles, pictures, and descriptions .

examples such as those found at the following link Google's developer:

http://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4

this is my full code

Anggra.java (this is main activity of my project)

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator;


public class Anggra extends ActionBarActivity {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TitlePageIndicator titlePageIndicator;

    private static final int numPages = 3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anggra);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        titlePageIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
        titlePageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_anggra, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Welcome();
                    getPageTitle(position);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new ViewContent();
                    getPageTitle(position);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new ItemFragment();
                    getPageTitle(position);
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return numPages;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_anggra, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

ItemFragment.java

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra;


import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy.ResourcesAdapter;

public class ItemFragment extends Fragment{

    public ItemFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
        listView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

        Resources resources = getActivity().getResources();
        ResourcesAdapter resourcesAdapter = new ResourcesAdapter(resources, view, getActivity());
        resourcesAdapter.stringResource();
        return view;
    }
}
```

ViewContent.java

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy.CustomView;
import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy.FullView;
import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy.ParsedDataSet;
import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy.XmlContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class ViewContent extends Fragment{
    private TextView textView;
    private AbsListView listView;
    private ArrayList<ParsedDataSet> itemList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private XmlContentHandler xmlContentHandler;
    private String url = "http://oscom.meximas.com/imagelistview.xml";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        listView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        doParsing(view);

        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        setListViewClick(listView);

        return view;
    }

    public void doParsing(View view){
        if (isNetworkAvailable()){
            textView.setText("Loading...");
            new AsyncData().execute(url);
        }
        else
        {
            showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private class AsyncData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setTitle("Loading....");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try
            {
                SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

                xmlContentHandler = new XmlContentHandler();
                xmlReader.setContentHandler(xmlContentHandler);

                URL _url = new URL(params[0]);

                xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(_url.openStream()));

            }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            textView.setText("Read all epic episode of Anggra");

            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            itemList = xmlContentHandler.getListItem();
            if (null != itemList && itemList.size() != 0){
                for (int index = 0; index < itemList.size(); index++){
                    ParsedDataSet parsedDataSet = itemList.get(index);
                }
            }

            itemList = xmlContentHandler.getListItem();
            listView.setAdapter(new CustomView(getActivity(),itemList));
        }
    }

    private void setListViewClick (AbsListView listView){
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                itemList = xmlContentHandler.getListItem();
                if (null != itemList && itemList.size() != 0){
                    for (int index = 0; index < itemList.size(); index++){
                        ParsedDataSet parsedDataSet = itemList.get(index);

                        textView.setText(parsedDataSet.getDesc());

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullView.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadImg(String url, ImageView img){

        try{
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
            return;

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomView.java

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.R;



public class CustomView extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ParsedDataSet> dataSets;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CustomView(Context context, ArrayList<ParsedDataSet> itemList)
    {
        mContext = context;
        dataSets = itemList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataSets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder vh;

        if(convertView == null){
            vh= new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
            vh.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            vh.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            vh.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            vh.tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            vh.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }
        else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ParsedDataSet parsedDataSet = dataSets.get(position);


        vh.tv1.setText(parsedDataSet.getTitle());
        vh.tv2.setText(parsedDataSet.getDesc());
        vh.tv3.setText(parsedDataSet.getPubDate());
        vh.tv4.setText(parsedDataSet.getLink());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv1,tv2,tv3, tv4;
        ImageView img;
    }


}
```

ParseDataSet.java

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy;

/**
 * Created by akew on 1/14/2015.
 */
public class ParsedDataSet {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private String pubDate;
    private String link;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

ResourcesAdapter.java

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.R;

/**
 * Created by akew on 1/8/2015.
 */
public class ResourcesAdapter {
    Resources mResources;
    View mView;
    Activity mActivity;
    String[] strings;
    AbsListView mListView;
    ListAdapter mAdapter;
    TextView mTextView;


    public ResourcesAdapter(Resources resources, View view, Activity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
        mResources = resources;
        mView = view;
        mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }

    public void stringResource(){
        strings = mResources.getStringArray(R.array.list_title);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mActivity
        , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
        , android.R.id.text1
        , strings);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        setListViewClick(mListView);
    }

    private void setListViewClick(AbsListView mListView){
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                mTextView = (TextView) view;
                Toast.makeText(mActivity
                , mTextView.getText()
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XmlContentHandler.java

```
package com.tolhedo.akew.anggra.dummy;


import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;



/**
 * Created by akew on 1/14/2015.
 */
public class XmlContentHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = "";
    ParsedDataSet parsedDataSet = null;

    private ArrayList<ParsedDataSet> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<ParsedDataSet> getListItem() {
        return itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = true;
        currentValue = "";
        if (localName.equals("item")){
            parsedDataSet = new ParsedDataSet();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = false;

        if (localName.equals("id")){
            parsedDataSet.setId(currentValue);
        }

        else if (localName.equals("title")){
            parsedDataSet.setTitle(currentValue);
        }
        else if (localName.equals("desc")){
            parsedDataSet.setDesc(currentValue);
        }
        else if (localName.equals("pubDate")){
            parsedDataSet.setPubDate(currentValue);
        }
        else if (localName.equals("link")){
            parsedDataSet.setLink(currentValue);
        }
        else if (localName.equals("item")){
            itemList.add(parsedDataSet);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (currentElement){
            currentValue = currentValue + new String(ch, start, length);
        }
    }
}
```

thank you for help

Comment: So where is your code, how do you try to handle it?
It looks like they are launching a new activity, having all the deatiled information in it, when clicking on the name.
Inform yourseld about the onclick event in listViews and onClick Launch an activity, which then pulls the detailed information.

Comment: I'm sorry for this inconvenience. I 've improved my question that does not make you become confused thank you very much for your help.